# Chrome never stops loading when flagging a post

Tags: bug, google-chrome, ipad

I've noticed that when I open the modal flag screen on SO, the loading icon in Chrome never stops showing activity, even when the *flag for moderator attention* window is closed.

I'm using Chrome on the iPad.

This also occurs when favouriting a question.

Comment: @Mat - Never Stops Loading, I've expanded the question title

Comment: Version? I've never seen this issue myself.

Comment: @Bart - 21.0.1180.82 - only on the mobile version

Comment: Can't reproduce on Android Chrome. Don't own an iPad though.